# SugarCRM: PHP not being executed from ajax on custom button

Tags: php, ajax, sugarcrm

I'm having some trouble with an ajax call on a custom button. The custom button is on the cases list view, and there is one for each case in the list. When clicked, this button should execute an ajax call to a custom endpoint, update the assigned_user_id to the currently logged in user, and redirect to the case which the button is associated with.

Currently, I'm hitting the endpoint, and can log the ID of the case being sent over via the ajax call, but can't get the call to update the case assigned user.

Here is the ajax call:

```
function take_ticket(url, id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/custom/modules/Cases/assign_ticket.php',
        contentType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
        success: function(response){
            window.location = url;
            //alert(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And here is the custom endpoint I created (note I'm hard-coding the user ID for testing):

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id']) {
    $test = $_GET['id'];
    updateUser($test);
}

function updateUser($test) {
    $case = new aCase();
    $case->retrieve($test);
    $case->assigned_user_id = 'a5c636c4-9712-d84a-7e81-585becf9dc52'
    $case->save();  
}
?>
```

If I remove all of the case creation/update logic and just echo $test, I get the response back that I would expect. However, with the update logic in place, my response is empty even if I simply echo $test, and the case does not get updated.

Edit: Due to getting an invalid entry point error, I tried adding an entry point for modules/Cases/case.php in include/MVC/Controller/entry_point_registry.php:

```
$entry_point_registry = array(
    'cases' => array('file' => 'modules/Cases/Case.php', 'auth' => false),
    'takeTicket' => array('file' => 'custom/modules/Cases/assign_ticket.php', 'auth' => false),
    'emailImage' => array('file' => 'modules/EmailMan/EmailImage.php', 'auth' => false),
.....
```

This didn't work, so I added an entry to custom/Extension/application/Ext/EntryPointRegistry/customEntryPoint.php:

```
$entry_point_registry['takeTicket'] = array(
    'file' => 'custom/modules/Cases/assign_ticket.php',
    'auth' => false
);

$entry_point_registry['cases'] = array(
    'file' => 'modules/Cases/Case.php',
    'auth' => false
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few changes to make in the files based on the information provided:

custom/modules/Cases/assign_ticket.php

```
$case->assigned_user_id = 'a5c636c4-9712-d84a-7e81-585becf9dc52'; //Added semicolon (syntax error)
```

custom/Extension/application/Ext/EntryPointRegistry/customEntryPoint.php

```
    'auth' => true //You need to be authenticated/authorised to perform saves on records
```

Ajax:

```
        url: 'index.php?entryPoint=takeTicket', //If you check the Sugar docs carefully, you'll see that the URL you need to call is index.php?entryPoint={yourEntryPointRegistryKey}
```

Comment: Ah, good catch, but that didn't fix the issue. To test, I removed the assignment and save lines and just tried to return the ID of the retrieved case, but it doesn't look like it's creating the case at all. I tried to include the Case.php, but get an invalid entry point response. I also tried to add the case class file as an entry point, but got the same results.

Comment: Okay, in that case, how are you adding the custom entry point? Can you advise the locations of the code you referenced above?

Comment: I assumed it couldn't create the case object because it wasn't finding the class declaration, so I included modules/Cases/Case.php. I defined the entry point first in include/MVC/Controller/entry_point_registry.php. That didn't work, so I tried defining it in a custom entry point file as described in Sugar's developer guide in custom/Extension/application/Ext/EntryPointRegistry. Note that this worked to define the entry point for the file I'm hitting with my ajax request.

Comment: Okay, could you please provide all of your current code, including the file in EntryPointRegistry, and the locations of all of the code you referenced above. Will make it easier for me to replicate and hopefully fix.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the few changes I made in order for it to work my side.